# Denoise is not showing in the Scene tab

Tags: denoise

I am using version 2.79, yet the Denoise option is not showing in the Render Layer Scene Tab.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're using [Blender Internal](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/introduction.html). Denoising is only available with [Cycles Render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/introduction.html).

You can change the render engine in the *info header* at the top of the window:

[image]